# FreeForm File Upload

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a form that has a file field on it. I think I am missing something simple. The code for the form is as follows:

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="product_support" required="customer_name|email" return="contact/thanks" notify_admin="yes" admin_notification_template="product_support" form:id="freeform" form:class="contact-form"}
<label for="support-logs">Upload error logs as a zip file</label>
<input type="file" id="support-logs" name="file1">
<button type="submit" class="submit bordered blue arrow">Submit</button>{/exp:freeform:form}
```

The form submits and all of the values are stored but for whatever reason the file that was specified does not get saved. I have verified that in FreeForm 4.0.10 the field exists, is assigned to the proper form and has file upload as it's type. I also verified that the location on the server exists and is set to 777.

There seemed to be more parameters with FreeForm 3.x so I was looking for those in the documents but did not see them. Perhaps I am missing things like file_upload/allowed_file_types and the like? Or maybe the CP settings have taken over this functionality.

Thoughts?

ANSWER:
Since StackExchange won't allow me to answer my question yet I'll edit here to give the answer.

Changed the input field for the file upload to a FreeForm field like so:

```
{freeform:field:file1 show="1"}
```

Works like a charm now.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 so you will have enough rep to post answers straight away in future :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had an old template that wasn't using the freeform field tags, this fixed it.

Comment: How do I get a pic of me.teying to download it but it was not a good picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening since we moved file fields to custom fields in Freeform 4 `enctype="multipart/form-data"` doesn't get added automatically to the  element opener.

If you want to do file fields manually you can use the param `form:enctype="multipart/form-data"` which will add the param to the opening  element.

Answer (score 1):

Since StackExchange won't allow me to answer my question yet I'll edit here to give the answer.

Changed the input field for the file upload to a FreeForm field like so:

```
{freeform:field:file1 show="1"}
```

Works like a charm now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a parameter like?

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Nevermind. According to Solspace forums: "The enctype=”” parameter doesn’t exist in Freeform. Freeform should take care of outputting this form parameter automatically for you"