# Solspace: Freeform - attachments not uploading

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Freeform: 4.1.2 
EE 2.7.0

Trying to upload a file with an entry. So far no success.

I referenced this [post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/freeform-file-upload)

Here is my code:

```
{exp:freeform:form
   form_id="1"
   required="name|email|phone1|experience"
   return="page/thank-you"
   notify_admin="yes"
   notify_admin_template="contact"
   file_upload="Resume Uploads"
   send_attachment="yes"  
}
```

I tried this for the input field - it looks right but does not upload the file.

```
<input type="file"{freeform:field:file1 show="1"}
```

So I tried this and it simply creates a text area with no file upload options.

```
{freeform:field:file1 show="1"}
```

I have searched the Solspace [documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#file_upload), but there are no examples and the file upload code does not help.

I would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my template, the field looks like this:
{freeform:field:attach_your_resume}

First, I would try removing the part of your tag that says "show=1" and just use:
{freeform:field:file1}

Second, did you create the field called "file1" (from the freeform admin inside EE)  And if so, what filetypes did you set it up to accept?

Also, in Expression Engine, have you set it up to allow those kinds of file uploads?  Look in:
Content->Files->File Upload Preferences
and look at the Allowed File Types for your file upload location.

Then, if that still isn't working, you may need to look at your mimes.php file which is found inside the Expression Engine core.

Comment: Enga, you were spot on. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: great! I'm glad it worked!

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `file_upload=""` and `send_attachment="yes"` are not valid parameters in `{exp:freeform:form}`. Parameters are listed here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#parameters